# How to skip the rendering of an element of a React functional component when loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple functional component in React, that renders the search results. If there are results, it renders the names of users, if there are no results, it renders a message `no public records found`. The problem is that the message is rendered when the component is loaded, whereas I want to show it only when there are no results in `serp` array. I don't want to change it into class component just because of that, and I'm sure there's a way to "skip" the rendering of the message when the component loads.

Could you help figure it out?

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const SearchResults = ({ auth: { user }, search: { users, loading } }) => {
  let serp;

  if (users.length !== 0) {
    serp = users.map((item, i) => {
      return <div key={i}>{item.name}</div>;
    });
  } else {
    return <div>no public record found</div>;
  }

  return <div className="dashboard-container">{serp}</div>;
};

SearchResults.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  search: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  search: state.search
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(SearchResults));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of loading like this:

```js
const SearchResults = ({ auth: { user }, search: { users, loading } }) => {
  let serp;

  if (users.length !== 0) {
    serp = users.map((item, i) => {
      return <div key={i}>{item.name}</div>;
    });
  } else {
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>no public record found</div>;
    }
  }

  return <div className="dashboard-container">{serp}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Since SuleymanSah has suggested that you should make use of the `loading` prop to create a loading effect, below is my suggestion for better readability:

1. Create a HOC called `withLoading` like this:

```
const withLoading = isLoading => WrappedComponent =>
  isLoading ? <div>Loading...</div> : WrappedComponent;
```

2. Make use of `withLoading` like this inside your component:

```
const SearchResults = ({ auth: { user }, search: { users, loading } }) => {
  ...
  return (
   <div className="dashboard-container">
     {withLoading(loading)(...)}
   </div>;
  )
};
```

Having too many `if/else` like that will slow you down while reading code in the future. Please also consider using [Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator) for better readability too.